# Insights from Labor Demand Research

Tags: labor-economics, theory-of-the-firm

A few years ago during my PhD, I remember listening to a provocative keynote talk at a conference by [Francis Kramarz](https://faculty.crest.fr/fkramarz/) who criticized the progress in labor demand research. He summarizes his opinion in a short comment in [Labor Economics (Volume 30, October 2014, Page 12)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0927537114000906):

> In the end, we need to understand labor demand. As of today, I do not think that Labor Economics is endowed with the right tools, either theoretical or empirical, to embark in this task.

Since then, has there been more progress in understanding how firms work from within and how the succeed (beyond single firm examinations)?

I am especially interested in research which aligns the  rigor of economics (e.g. based on large-scale longitudinal linked-employer-employee data) with the relevance of the management literature (e.g. elaborate case-studies). Examples would be the [Bloom & van Reenen Management Practices articles](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/jep.24.1.203) among others.